# Magento 2: Cart price rule performance issue

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3, performance

I have imported 6.3 million coupon in Magento 2.3. I have performance issues on checkout page. When I apply coupon it takes lot of minutes. How to increase performance ?

I am running database on separate server which is fast and also I have setup  glera cluster.

Comment: Make sure you have index for `code` column in `salesrule_coupon` table.

Comment: Why you have created 6.3M Coupon?

Comment: I do not think Magento can handle it  this amount of Coupon

Comment: @dudzio it is already there. it is by default.

Comment: @AmitBera because we have these coupon in old website and i imported all coupon in magento.Then how big websites are handling million of coupons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated magento version from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 and my issue is fixed. Now i have 6.3 millions coupons and on magento latest version i am able to apply coupons without any issue. There is no performance issue in magento2.3.1 version.

Comment: There was a massive performance issue in the SQL Query of former versions of Magento 2, which basically prevented the usage of indexes in the salesrule_coupon table. According to Github the issue will be fixed in 2.3.2 but if you say it’s fixed already, that’s awesome. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/20484